# Global filter data by "Measure Names" in Tableau

Tags: filter, dashboard, tableau-api

I'm creating a dashboard to present data around veterans homelessness. I have 8 different data sources because of how we must blend our data and in dealing with certain confidentiality issues.

All my sources have four "system components" in common. In all my charts I select the default "Measure Names" to be my dimension and the default "Measure Values" to be my measure. In individual charts, I'm able to filter by "measure names" to see the data for each system component, however when placed on a dashboard I've been unable to make this filter apply to all the different charts that need it.

I've tried to apply the filter through actions on the dashboard, but I can't seem to get it to work. The only solution I've found promise in is converting the measures through parameters and calculated fields, but I've not had success with that either.

How can I turn the default "Measure Names" dimension into a global filter?

Comment: You're better off posting on the Tableau Community Forum than here would be my opinion.  That being said, you can right click a filter and say apply to all sources - not an Action.

Comment: A filter is scoped ot